# EF Core Relationships one-to-many-to-many FluentAPI

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Boa tarde,
Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida de relacionamento no Entity Core.
Tenho uma tabela pessoa e a pessoa tem um cargo (Gerente, supervisor, responsável, etc..)

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CargoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cargo { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Cargo
{
    public int CargoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Pessoas { get; private set; }
}
```

Até o momento não tenho dúvidas.

Agora vamos supor que tenho uma tabela Sala e essa sala tem um Gerente, um supervisor e um responsável, que são Pessoas. Como ficaria o relacionamento ?

Assim:

```
public class Sala
{
    public int SalaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int ResponsavelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Responsavel {get; set; }
    public int SupervisorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Supervisor {get; set; }
    public int GerenteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Gerente {get; set; }

}
```

E alteraria Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CargoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cargo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection Salas { get; private set; }
}
```

E criaria o relacionamento no de cada campo no Fluent API com a propriedade Salas ou

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CargoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cargo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection SalaResponsavel { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection SalaSupervisor { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection SalaGerente { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nessa forma que está fazendo, ficaria assim:

```
 public virtual Sala SalaResponsavel { get; private set; }
 public virtual Sala SalaSupervisor { get; private set; }
 public virtual Sala SalaGerente { get; private set; }
```

Mas, acho que fica um tanto bagunçado, acho que faria outra tabela contendo

```
Sala
Pessoa
Cargo
```

Assim a relação ficaria de n-n

Estou pelo celular agora, a noite tento complementar mais a resposta

Comment: Acho que entendi sua ideia. Mas o que acontece é que as pessoas já possuem um cargo independente de estarem associadas a sala ou não. Por isso hoje eu tenho a tabela Pessoa e a Cargo. Na salas eu tenho que vincular pessoas que possuem determinados Cargos. Talvez eu possa criar uma tabela para fazer um n-n tipo PessoasSala mas não ficaria explicito os cargos que tenho que associar.

Comment: Acredito que https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745465/ef-core-many-to-many-relationship-on-a-class resolva meu problema. Amanhã vou testar e retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Para o meu contexto a resposta do link abaixo foi a solução.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745465/ef-core-many-to-many-relationship-on-a-class

Fiz o mapeamento e a entidade carregou sem problema. Agora com o Dapper preenche os dados. Obrigado.